# copying specific value x times into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, data-transform

I am having a hard time transforming an unstructured data thats in an excel sheet into a structured tabular format in python so I can do data analysis on it.

I want to copy the location (i.e. Paris) into `Col 4` to its corresponding rows. The rows below `# of x` represent one person, which can vary. For example Milan has 3 entries while London has 4.

Additionally, removing the rows with no entries like Paris and Rome.

I kind of have an idea but do not know how to implement it. If `Col 2` is not `# of Cafes to Visit` or not a numeric then copy that value into `Col 4` until you find the next entry...not sure about this though :(

Can someone help me?

Input:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location | Paris |  |  |
| # of Shops To Visit | # of Cafes to Visit | # of Museums to Visit |  |
| Location | Milan |  |  |
| # of Shops To Visit | # of Cafes to Visit | # of Museums to Visit |  |
| 3 | 5 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |  |
| 5 | 6 | 7 |  |
| Location | London |  |  |
| # of Shops To Visit | # of Cafes to Visit | # of Museums to Visit |  |
| 6 | 6 | 2 |  |
| 3 | 5 | 0 |  |
| 5 | 4 | 1 |  |
| 5 | 4 | 1 |  |
| Location | Rome |  |  |
| # of Shops To Visit | # of Cafes to Visit | # of Museums to Visit |  |

Output:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | Milan |
| 2 | 4 | 4 | Milan |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | Milan |
| 6 | 6 | 2 | London |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | London |
| 5 | 4 | 1 | London |
| 5 | 4 | 1 | London |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To approach this problem, I first gathered the cities individually:

```
data = pd.read_csv(path,delim_whitespace=True,header=None,names=['col1','col2','col3'])
cities = data[data['col1']=='Location']['col2'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

I then figured out which row would apply to each city in the above data series by finding when the data in 'col3' was not null:

```
city_inds = np.cumsum(np.logical_not(pd.notna(data['col3'])))-1
```

Finally, you can use these indices into the original cities data series to allocate the correct city into to the original dataframe. Then, we can drop the rows that are irrelevant:

```
data['cities'] = cities.iloc[city_inds].reset_index(drop=True)
data = data[data['col1'].str.isnumeric()].reset_index(drop=True)  #drop rows which aren't numeric in col1
Out[]:   col1 col2 col3  cities
0     3    5    3   Milan
1     2    4    4   Milan
2     5    6    7   Milan
3     6    6    2  London
4    3    5    0  London
5    5    4    1  London
6    5    4    1  London
```

Comment: thankyou! :) I looked up the documentation for all three functions used in `city_inds = np.cumsum(np.logical_not(pd.notna(data['col3'])))-1`, but Im confused how its able to keep count and update when its a new city. Do you mind explaining? @jhso

Comment: 1. notna will return False when the data is null (what we're looking for as it indicates the location and city is in that row). 2. logical_not flips this so we have True where the NaNs are. 3. Cumsum will increment every time we see a NaN in this column, which will give us the city index (after subtracting 1 so it starts at 0) for all of the numeric data in the cities DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#Removing the rows with no entries like Paris and Rome.
df['dummy'] = df['Col 2'].replace('# of Cafes to Visit|[0-9]+', np.nan, regex=True).ffill()
df = df.groupby('dummy').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2).drop(columns=['dummy'])

#Moving Locations to Col 4
df['Col 4'].fillna(df['Col 2'], inplace=True)
df['Col 4'].replace('# of Cafes to Visit|[0-9]+', np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
df['Col 4'].ffill(inplace=True)

df = df[~df['Col 1'].isin(['# of Shops To Visit', 'Location'])]
df[['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3']] = df[['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3']].replace(r'\D+', np.nan, regex=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
  Col 1 Col 2 Col 3   Col 4
0     3     5     3   Milan
1     2     4     4   Milan
2     5     6     7   Milan
3     6     6     2  London
4     3     5     0  London
5     5     4     1  London
6     5     4     1  London
```